# VB.Net String in Vietnamese Character

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, encoding

Good day to all. I'm working on a project to connect WinForm application with a website using SOAP. I'm successfully got response from the website which means I'm able to send data to the website in XML format.

However, the website is supposed to be in Vietnamese language. Data that I send from Winform is incorrect. Some string sent to the website is not in Vietnamese word.

For example:

Word CHI NHAÙNH supposed to be [image].

I set `RichTextBox` with Vietnamese font and it shown correctly in the GUI. And I know it only on the interface only. I already test several ways such as `Encoding.UTF8`, `Encoding.Unicode` and `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("vi-VN")` to the string but it did not return correct string as I wanted. I also tested to translate the string to Vietnamese wording but also didn't work.

Here is part of my XML string:

```
        InvoiceXML = "<?xml version=""" & "1.0" & """ encoding=""" & "utf-8" & """?>"

        InvoiceXML = InvoiceXML + ("<Invoices>")
        InvoiceXML = InvoiceXML + ("<Inv>")

        InvoiceXML = InvoiceXML + ("<key></key>")

        InvoiceXML = InvoiceXML + ("<Invoice>")

        InvoiceXML = InvoiceXML + ("<CusCode>" & RS.Rows(0).Item("CustomerNo") & "</CusCode>")

        InvoiceXML = InvoiceXML + ("<Buyer></Buyer>")

        InvoiceXML = InvoiceXML + ("<CusName><![CDATA[ " & String.Format(Trim(txtCustNameX.Text), Encoding.UTF8) & " ]]></CusName>")

        InvoiceXML = InvoiceXML + ("<CusAddress><![CDATA[ " & String.Format(txtAdd1X.Text, Encoding.UTF8) & " " & String.Format(txtAdd2X.Text, Encoding.UTF8) & " ]]></CusAddress>")
```

Then I place XML string to `RichTextBox` named as `txtXML`. And here is the code to send XML string to website:

```
    Dim MyImport As PublishService = New PublishService

    Dim MyResponse = MyImport.ImportInv(String.Format(txtXML.Text, Encoding.UTF8), XUserName, XPassword, 1)
```

`ImportInv`  expecting string, string, string, and integer.

Is there any way I can achieve this? Any help is highly appreciated.
Apologize for not provide my codes previously.

Comment: Show us the code. This is not a request we should have to make. Assume that you must ALWAYS show us the code.

Comment: Culture and Encoding are not the same thing. A Web Site usually expects text data encoded in UTF-8, but it may also use the local encoding (or, one of the local encodings, this still happens). Almost none is using UTF16-LE (Encoding.Unicode). As mentioned, the code you're using is the important part.

Comment: I already post my codes. Apologize for not posting my codes previously.

Comment: the code may be good.  The tool you are using to view the data may not be using the correct encoding (or font).

Comment: [String.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format) doesn't have an overload that accepts an *encoding* as 2nd parameter, and it would be useless anyway. An encoding is only needed when translating a string into bytes (or back)

Comment: Thanks for all feedback. Any suggestion to solve this? I'm stuck with this issue for several days now.

Comment: What does `MyImport.ImportInv` do with that XML-string? Can you specify an encoding when you actually send that data? Does it really match the encoding that the other side expects?

Comment: OT there are better ways of building an XML string. For a minimum, look into StringBuilder. But preferably something that understands XML and handles escaping for you automatically

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out by storing correct Vietnamese word in SQL Server with data type `nvarchar`. During updating the Vietnamese word to database, I add `N` before actual values.

For example:

```
Update tablename Set columnname = N'values'
```